# What does "outlier organization" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "outlier organization" mean in "XXX is an outlier organization in the world of turning science fiction into reality."?

Comment: Did you check 'outlier' in a dictionary?

Comment: Sure, but it does not help. Outlier: a person or thing situated away or detached from the main body or system

Comment: So XXX is an organisation away from the main set of organizations turning science fiction into reality. An organization that is different or unusual or untypical in that field.

Comment: Yeah, "outlier" is almost always used in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: BTW:  To avoid having your question closed for "lack of research", quote a few of the definitions or other details you found in your research.

Answer (score 1):

Edit for a more specific answer:

> "XXX is an outlier organization in the world of turning science fiction into reality."

XXX could be making everyone pay with bitcoin, or it could be the only organization that's actually selling while everyone else is going bankrupt. Pretty much anything can make it into an *outlier*.

An *outlier organization* is an *organization*, that is an *[outlier](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/outlier)* compared to other *organizations* in its field.

For example:
Tesla is an *outlier organization*, because it is an automotive company that does not offer any cars with combustion engines built in.

The local archery club is an *outlier organization*, because it is a sports club that is not funded by the state, but privately owned instead.

Oxford Learners Dictionaries on "outlier":

1. a person or thing that is different from or in a position away from others in the group

> They are corporate outliers, people who just don't fit into the
> culture of the company.

Comment: You still need to get rid of the misplaced apostrophe.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was going to complain that I didn't see what you meant at first, but then I read it again. Let me know if you notice something else!